# Identifying next closest record by date in tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I have a table of users and another table of transactions.

The transactions all have a date against them. What I am trying to ascertain for each user is the average time between transactions.

```
User | Transaction Date
-----+-----------------
A    | 2001-01-01
A    | 2001-01-10
A    | 2001-01-12
```

Consider the above transactions for user A. I am basically looking for the distance from one transaction to the next chronologically to determine the distances.

There are 9 days between transactions one and two; and there are 2 days between transactions three and four. The average of these is obviously 4.5, so I would want to identify the average time between user A's transactions to be 4.5 days.

Any idea of how to achieve this in Tableau?

I am trying to create a calculated field for each transaction to identify the date of the "next" transaction but I am struggling.

```
{ FIXED [user id] : MIN(IF [Transaction Date] > **this transaction date** THEN [Transaction Date]) }
```

I am not sure what to replace **this transaction date** with or whether this is the right approach at all.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LODs dont have access to previous values directly, so you need to create a self join in your data connection. Follow below steps to achieve what you want.

1. Create a self join with your data with following criteria

[image]

2. Create an LOD calculation as below

> {FIXED [User],[Transaction Date]:
>           MIN(DATEDIFF('day',[Transaction Date],[Transaction Date (Data1)]))
>       }

[image]

3. Build the View

[image]

PS: If you want to improve the performance, Custom SQL might be the way.

Answer (score 0):

The only type of calculation that can take order sequence into account (e.g., when the value for a calculated field depends on the value of the immediately preceding row) is a table calc. You can't use an LOD calc for this kind of problem.

You'll need to understand how partitioning and addressing works with table calcs, along with specifying your sort order criteria. See the online help. You can then do something like, for example, define **days_since_last_transaction** as:

`if first() > 0 then min([Transaction Date]) - 
 lookup(min([Transaction Date]), -1) end`

If you have very large data or for other reasons want to do your calculations at the database instead of in Tableau by a table calc, then you use SQL windowing (aka analytical) queries instead via Tableau's custom SQL.

Answer (score -1):

Please attach an example workbook and anything you tried along with the error you have.

This might not be useful if you cannot set User ID Field as a filter.

So, you can set

> User ID

as a filter. Then following the steps mentioned in [here](https://kb.tableau.com/articles/howto/calculate-difference-in-dates-with-one-date-field) will lead you to calculating difference between any two dates. Ideally if you select any one value in the filter, the calculated field from the link should give you the difference in the dates that you have in the transaction dates column.